# Parsing large xml files iphone more than 20 MB

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

i want to parse large xml file in iPhone and i have tried touch xml , gData and other xml parsers including SAX parsers .. my app crashes after parsing xml files or during parsing xmls because it keeps 40 MB of data in memory 
What would be the best way to parse large xml files ? i want to parse the data and insert it into core data.

Thanks Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) (under "Which to Choose" section):

> If you want to read extremely large XML documents, performance is the
>   critical issue here. You’ll want to consider libxml2 SAX, TBXML, or
>   libxml DOM for this, depending on what your exact situation is.

If you are parsing properly you shouldn't be holding 40MB of parsed data in memory. Be sure to batch insert the data into Core Data as you are parsing to avoid causing a memory warning and a crash of your app.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer , Actually i have a tree structure in xml so i need to have all the data in memory to find out parent and child elements also i have tried tbxml that reduces memory but my app is still using too much memory ... basic requirement is to access a tree based data so i can identify parent and child elements when inserting data into core data .

Comment: Can you please suggest anything for tree based parsing in which we need to know parent and child elements .. any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: What assumptions can be made about the data that you are parsing? (Is it ordered/organized in any way, etc?)

Comment: yes its like this: <Item><Items><Item><Items><Item></Item></Items></Item></Items></Item> children objects are dynamic and can be changed depending on the data.. and the format is "Items/Item" if we do xPath query. Thanks

Comment: What I am trying to figure out here is if it is possible for you to batch your saves to Core Data. So if you have a parent item that you for sure know is done being parsed (doesn't have any parents and all of its children are done), you should dump all the data for that object from memory into Core Data, and continue. In the event that you cannot, you may want to consider just doing an initial parse and dump of data (with metadata) into CD, then after the parsing is done you can construct the tree appropriately in CD with the help of your meta data.

Comment: i am doing batch insert in core data .. i have nsdictionary mapped with parent and child elements do you know how can we release data after doing a batch insert .. i am using arc in my project .

Comment: Check out this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1 and this one:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-CJBDBHCB I think those are what you are looking for. Never had to do that myself but looks promising.